# Where is the string operator " <- " defined in Scala?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am new to scala and I am bit confused by it. I use IntelliJ Idea. I know that Scala allows special characters to be used as methods. In IntelliJ Idea Command+Click on the method or Ctrl+Click moves you to where the method is defined. However, in Scala when I click on `<-` in a for loop it moves me to :

```
  def foreach[U](f: Char => U): Unit = { ... }
```

Although the question is about this particular operator, I would like to know how to find other operators are defined and why IntelliJ jumps to the `foreach` statement?

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/for-loops.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` comprehensions, just like any other language construct, are defined in the [Scala Language Specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/). More specifically, in [Section 6.19 *For Comprehensions and For Loops*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops).

In particular, the left arrow `<-` (which can alternatively also be written as `←`) is the syntax for defining a *generator*:

> A *generator*  `←`  produces bindings from an expression  which is matched in some way against pattern .

Comment: So, you mean that I can't see the class where this <- is defined? I am looking for something like def <- (a:params1, b:param2) = { ... } I want to see its source code

Comment: It is a language feature. Like every single other language feature, it is defined in the language specification. That is not something that is specific to `<-`, it is not even something specific to Scala. Libraries are defined in source code, language features are defined in the language specification.l

Comment: I see I've got confused because Scala allows special characters to be made as functionstion so I thought <- can be something like  a.<-(b) but it turns out that it is something like for or while constructs.

Comment: Exactly. Of course, for any given implementation, there will still be some place *in the compiler*, where those semantics are defined, but you will really have to go hunting in the bowels of the compiler to find it. Also, it will typically be defined in multiple places, at least in the lexer, parser, semantic analyzer, and code generator, and potentially the optimizer, too.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `<-` method in the `java.lang.String` or `scala.collection.immutable.StringOps` classes. It is just syntactic sugar for a `foreach` invocation as pointed out by intellij.

Comment: Yeah, definitely it is, but where this syntactic sugar is defined or it is embedded in Scala lang? Isn't this an alias that has to be defined somewhere ?